# Count the occurrence of one vector's values in another vector including non match values in R

Tags: r, vector, match

I have 2 vectors:

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I want to calculate the occurrence of values of v1 in v2. The expected result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 1 2 2 1 1 0
```

I know there is a function can do this:

```
table(v1[v1 %in% v2])
```

However, it only list the matched values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 1 2 2 1 1
```

How can I show all the values in v2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
table(factor(v1, levels=unique(v2)))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 2 1 2 2 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!